# How to find Toast notifications are enabled?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In Windows 8.1 you can disable notifications for 1, 3 or 8 hours or from app's settings -> permissions you can disable notifications.

How do I identify it in c# code so that I can display that same information as a `MessageDialog` rather using `ToastNotificationManager`

Answer (score 1):

This may not be applicable to Windows 8.1, but since I found this while looking for the equivalent in Windows 10...

Raymond Chen details this in an [Old New Thing blogpost](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200810-00/?p=104058).

Use the [`Setting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.setting) property of a `ToastNotifier` to tell if toasts have been disabled, and why.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that .. The best way is to build UI and let the user choose the time to send Toast OR `MessageDialog` .. And FYI : You can't show `MessageDialog` while your app is suspended, The required status is : `Activated` !